# static void pointer in AVFoundation.Framework in sample code

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, avfoundation

I am just going through the sample code of `AVFoundation.Framework` -> `AVSimpleEditoriOS` & I found following line which I could not understand.

```
static void *AVSEPlayerItemStatusContext = &AVSEPlayerItemStatusContext;
static void *AVSEPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay = &AVSEPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay;
```

consider following

```
static void *AVSEPlayerItemStatusContext = nil;
static void *AVSEPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay = nil;
```

Above two lines, I can figure out that those are 2 static void/generic pointers with some fancy name.

Now back to those 2 lines, I am pasting it here again,

```
static void *AVSEPlayerItemStatusContext = &AVSEPlayerItemStatusContext;
static void *AVSEPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay = &AVSEPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay;
```

Does above mean, 2 static void/generic pointers storing reference of it's own & why would be it needed in what sense?

I just need little guide to learn such coding pattern.
Awaiting for knowledge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *self-referencing pointer*

```
static void *foo = &foo;
```

is just ***a method to create a unique pointer at compile time***.

In that ["AVSimpleEditoriOS"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVSimpleEditoriOS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample project, these pointers are later used as `context` parameter for

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"player.currentItem.status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVSEPlayerItemStatusContext];
```

and

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playerLayer.readyForDisplay" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVSEPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay];
```

The actual value of the context parameter does not matter at all, it is just some unique
value that is passed to

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
     if (context == AVSEPlayerItemStatusContext) {
        // Notification for @"player.currentItem.status"
        // ...
     } else if (context == AVSEPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay) {
        // Notification for @"playerLayer.readyForDisplay"
        // ...
     } else {
        // Something else, pass to superclass:
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

<strike>(Alternatively, one could check the `keyPath` parameter in `observeValueForKeyPath`.)</strike>
See @Bavarious' comment below for why unique context pointers are generally preferred over key path strings.

Comment: Does it mean - we are passing it as context(just like an unique id of a record in database) & when receiving response from inner framework, we can identify response for the context?

Comment: @Spark: Yes, exactly. The context parameter of `addObserver` needs a pointer variable, so this is just a convenient method of creating a unique pointer variable. - I have extended the answer a bit to make the idea more clear.

Comment: Just one note: unique context pointers are generally preferred over key path strings because it is possible that one of the superclasses is also observing that same key path.

Comment: @Bavarious: The is indeed a very good point that I did not think about. I have updated the answer, thanks for the feedback!